# Routing table with 3 interfaces

Tags: networking, server

I am trying to set up on a server 2 networks which connect to the internet through a third interface. The topography is as follows :

- eth0 : 192.168.0.1 is the internet interface and routes through
  192.168.0.254
- eth1 : is one of the local networks : 172.16.1.0
- eth2 : is the other one : 172.16.2.0
  eth1 and eth2 are set-up in exactly the same way in /etc/network/interfaces

I have the following result from route :

```
> Kernel IP routing table 
> Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface 
> default         192.168.0.254   0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
> 172.16.1.0      *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
> 172.16.2.0      *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth2
> 192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

From any machine on 172.16.1.0 I can ping 8.8.8.8 or any address within my network. From machines on  172.16.2.0 and can only ping local machines and not access the Internet. So `ping 8.8.8.8` fails.

Why is this ? I have tried with ufw enabled and disabled. I do not understand why eth2 is not routed through eth0 to the internet !

Thank for the advice of using traceroute.
The server links well the 2 sub-networks. I connect from any machine on 172.16.1.x to any on 172.16.2.x and vice-versa. It seems the handling of the packets to the internet interface which poses problems for 172.16.2.0. Here are 2 traceroutes :

from machine 172.16.1.6 :

```
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  gaudi.wombats.org (172.16.1.1)  0.264 ms  0.257 ms  0.484 ms
 2  192.168.0.254 (192.168.0.254)  1.132 ms  1.130 ms  1.122 ms
 3  88.161.205.254 (88.161.205.254)  24.379 ms  24.837 ms  26.092 ms
```

from machine 172.16.2.2 :

```
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  172.16.2.1 (172.16.2.1)  0.338 ms  0.336 ms  0.318 ms
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  *^C
```

So although route indicates to that default is 192.168.0.254, it does not seem to apply for packets coming from 172.16.2.0.

Comment: Have you checked the logs? Maybe you can find come clues in the logs. Try traceroute or tracepath to see where the traffic stops. I don't see anything wrong.

Comment: Look at the output of  `route -n`  on the machines in your 172.16 networks and compare them. The machines in 172.16.2 should mention your server as a gateway, I think.

Answer (score 1):

The trick was simple, I forgot to allow the masquerading from interface eth2. So I added the following line to /etc/ufw/before.rules (after the same line for eth1) :

```
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.16.2.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

That did the trick !

Comment: Or you should have MASQUERADE 172.16.0.0/22 instead of only 172.16.1.0/24.  Best if you named your networks 172.16.0.0/24 and 172.16.1.0/24, then they could be combined to 172.16.0.0/23.  Use the program sipcalc to see how netmasks works, by applying each of the network addresses and netmasks as argument. You can use CIDR format as you have used here.